# The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to float

Tags: java, overloading

I hit a bump when I'm doing my Java code. I feel like I somehow got the concept messed up, like I not sure for this:

```
void setScore(float[] sco)
{
    sco = score;
}

public void setScore(float sco, int id)
{
    sco[id] = score;
}
```

The error message corresponds to "sco[ID] = score; "

```
The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to float
```

I'm confused what I should put in the bracket, the book asks me to put "float[] score" instead of "float[] sco", but it doesn't work, so I edited a bit after several trials. This part of coding generally describes the method of overloading that stores the score for 5 subjects.

And this is my whole coding:

```
public class Score {
float math, english, physics, chemistry, biology;
float sum, average;
float[] score;
int id;

void setMath(float Math) {
    math = Math;
}

void setEnglish(float English) {
    english = English;
}

void setPhysics(float Physics) {
    physics = Physics;
}

void setChemistry(float Chemistry) {
    chemistry = Chemistry;
}

void setBiology(float Biology) {
    biology = Biology;
}

void setSum(float Sum) {
    sum = math + english + physics + chemistry + biology;
}

void setAverage(float Average) {
    average = sum / 5;
}

float getMath() {
    return math;
}

float getEnglish() {
    return english;
}

float getPhysics() {
    return physics;
}

float getChemistry() {
    return chemistry;
}

float getBiology() {
    return biology;
}

float getSum() {
    return sum;
}

float getAverage() {
    return average;
}

public void setScore(float[] sco)
{
    sco = score;
}

public void setScore(float sco, int id)
{
    sco[id] = score;
}
}
```

Now my problem solved! Since I just changed like this:

```
    public void score()
{

}
public void setScore(float[] score)
{
    sco = score;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why now the problem resolved? Will really appreciate a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a value of the class variable `score` to the parameter `sco` when you should do the **opposite**. In other words:

Your code says:

```
sco = score;
```

But what you should do is:

```
score = sco;
```

In both functions you need to **switch the order** of `score` and `sco` so that `score` gets the value of `sco`.

As far as your error, in `setScore(float sco, int id)` you defined parameter `sco` as a `float` but you are trying to access it as an array (by saying `sco[Id] = score`). That is why you are getting your error message.

```
The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to float
```

Like I said, you can fix this by switching the order again:

```
sco[Id] = score;
```

Into:

```
score[Id] = sco;
```

**EDIT:**

As far as this part:

> I'm confused what I should put in the bracket, the book asks me to put "float[] score"     > instead of "float[] sco", but it doesn't work, so I edited a bit after several trials. This     > part of coding generally describes the method of overloading that stores the score for 5 > subjects.

Since you wanted to know how to use the same names for parameters and class variables, as @Smutje mentioned, you should use the keyword `this`.

That way, there is no ambiguity with which `score` you are using:

- `this.score` belongs to your class called `Score` and can be used in any function inside the class. It is visible to everything inside the class.
- `score` is a function parameter local to a function `setScore()` and can only be used inside `setScore()`. It is only visible inside the function.

Therefore, including everything mentioned, you should make the following changes:

Change:

```
public void setScore(float sco, int id)
{
    sco[id] = score;
}

void setScore(float[] sco)
{
    sco = score;
}
```

To:

```
public void setScore(float score, int id) // changed sco to score
{
    this.score[id] = score;   // switched order, added keyword this
}

void setScore(float[] score) // changed sco to score
{
    this.score = score;  // switched order, added keyword this
}
```

Comment: You are very welcome. If you find an answer helpful/correct, upvote and accept so people will know this questions is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mixed up the variable names:

```
void setScore(float[] sco)
{
    sco = score;
}

public void setScore(float sco, int id)
{
    sco[id] = score;
}
```

because `score` is the field which you want to populate and `sco` is the parameter which you want to populate `score` with. The code above does not change any contents of `Score`, so try to swap it to

```
void setScore(float[] sco)
{
    this.score = sco;
}

public void setScore(float sco, int id)
{
    this.score[id] = sco;
}
```

it also would have helped if you have started using `this` to mark instance fields explicitly.

Comment: So generally i can say i should use "this" when i want to name some parameters from the original field?

Comment: Yes, one should - not necessary, but it helps.

Comment: Yup it is much convenient, thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Check again how you set your score:

```
void setScore(float[] sco)
{
    sco = score;
}
```

What is `sco`? What you want to assign to what?

> You are assigning your local variable to the parameter. It should be the other way around. `(this.score = sco)`